# Catching img load error for <img> tags created after page load (e.g. via AJAX)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, events

I'm using jQuery's `error` event handler to catch image loading errors. It looks like this:

```
$(function(){
  $('img').error(function(){
    // ... do something
  })
})
```

This works great for images that are in the DOM when the page is loaded. However, I'd like to catch the errors for `<img>` tags that get inserted via AJAX, too. I'd prefer to not have to run certain code after every AJAX call.

I'd like something like this, although this doesn't seem to work:

```
$('body').on('error', 'img', function(){
  // ... do something
})
```

Comment: http://www.unseenrevolution.com/jquery-ajax-error-handling-function/
May be this will help you.

Comment: Wish I could find out why .on doesn't work with 'error' as I've had to give up and repeatedly call $('img').error instead.

Comment: `on` does work with error. You just can't delegate it as the event doesn't bubble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to set the binding after every ajax call, you might want to set it in a global ajax complete function

```
//Gloabal Ajax Complete
$("body").bind("ajaxSend", function(e, xhr, settings){
   //Sent
}).bind("ajaxComplete", function(e, xhr, settings){
   //Complete
   $('img').error(function(){
       // ... do something
   })
}).bind("ajaxError", function(e, xhr, settings, thrownError){
    //Error
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use jQuery's live() or delegate() or on() methods depending on jQuery version you're using to register the error event on current and future image elements you add to the document. Refer http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: As you can see, I tried that and it doesn't seem to work. I've used `live` and `on` (`delegate` is just `on` with arguments in a different order)

Comment: The error event doesn't bubble according to this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/error